# Better way to assign a categorical variable to a group using dplyr?

Tags: r, group-by, filtering, dplyr

I'm trying to assign a categorical variable (yes or no) to a group based on two other calculated categorical variables, both containing 'yes' or 'no' categories. I want the entire group to be to be assigned 'yes' if one row has a yes for both of the previously two calculated variables. There must be a better way to do this with a filter or some windowed rank function. Here is the messy code that I've come up with so far to do it. `filteredDF` is the output that I'm hoping to get. Thanks!

```
#install.packages('nycflights13', 'dplyr')
library('nycflights13')
library('dplyr')
data(flights)

filteredDF <- flights %>%
  mutate(variable1 = ifelse(month %in% c(1:6) & day %in% c(16:28), yes = 'yes', no = 'no')) %>% #create first calculated categorical variable
  mutate(variable2 = ifelse(month %in% c(7:12, 6) & day %in% c(1:16) , yes = 'yes', no = 'no')) %>% #create second calculated categorical variable
  group_by(tailnum) %>% # assign groups I'm interested in
  mutate(varTogether = ifelse('yes' %in% variable1 & 'yes' %in% variable2, yes = 'yes', no = 'no')) %>% # create 3rd categorical to filter by (assigned by group)
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(varTogether == 'yes') # filter out what I want
```

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer Thanks I'll add that to the question

Comment: You don't need to do that.  You can just type `flights` after loading the package, but it's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it seems easier to use logical variables (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) rather than categorical (`'yes'`/`'no'`) variables ... this doesn't shorten things very much, but it does clean them up a bit.

```
filteredDF <- flights %>%
  mutate(variable1 = month %in% 1:6  & day %in% 16:28,
         variable2 = month %in% 7:12 & day %in% 1:16) %>% 
  group_by(tailnum) %>% 
  mutate(varTogether = any(variable1) & any(variable2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(varTogether)
```

(I'm assuming that `c(7:12, 6)` was a mistake. Also, did you really want the day range for the two variables to overlap?)

You could shorten it up a little bit by omitting intermediate variables, but that might be less readable. (Or you could define a function `vt <- function(month,day) any(...) & any(...)`)

```
filteredDF <- flights %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>% 
  mutate(varTogether=any(month %in% 1:6  & day %in% 16:28) &
                     any(month %in% 7:12 & day %in% 1:16)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(varTogether)
```

Comment: I like both of those solutions, both seem more readable. And as for the day/month overlap I didn't initially intend for them to overlap, but in my haste to ask the question with a publicly available data set I just wanted something that would result in a valid data frame. I now realize that they didn't need to overlap for that to happen. Thanks for your help!